# Group 2 columns and sum values for another column

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

I have the following problem: I need to group data and perform a sum in another column in libreoffice calc/excel spreadsheet, just like a group by would do in SQL

In the following example, I would like the cells A26, A27 to become one line, and cell C26 should be the sum of the 2 rows.
[image]

Comment: Why not just use a pivot table? Or does it have to be in the same location / format as the original is?

Answer (score 0):

Try on E26 cell the formula `=($A26 & $B27)` (Or `=($A26 & (-$B27))` if you want a dash between A26 and B27).

And on F26 cell `=($C26+$C27)` for the sum of rows.

Copy/Paste for the other cells of each col